# Can't seem to access individual objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is how I am fetching data and pushing it from the API call

```
const products_array = []

let imgx = null
 
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/products').then((res) => {

    for ( let key in res.data) {
        if( imagesArray[key].name === res.data[key].name) {
            imgx = imagesArray[key].img 
        }
        products_array.push({
            name: res.data[key].name,
            price: res.data[key].price,
            stock: res.data[key].stock,
            InStock: res.data[key].InStock,
            category: res.data[key].category,
            image: imgx
        })
    }}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)})
```

Now for some reason can't use the map function for this array after importing 'products_array' as 'productsArray' into another file

```
productsArray.map((product) => {
PRODUCT_PRICES_ARRAY.push({
    name : product.name,
    price : product.price
    })
CART_ARRAY.push({
    name: product.name
})
for(let i=0; i < CART_ARRAY.length; i++) {
CART[CART_ARRAY[i].name] = 0}
```

but when I hardcode it like this

```
 const products = [{
"name" : "Spinach",
"price" : 3,
"InStock" : true,
"stock" : 30,
"category" : "veg",
"image" :Spinach}, ....
```

the map function works totally fine.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is this related to reactjs? If you want to fetch data from your backend to display it in a react component then this is not the way to do it. You need to fetch data in `componentDidMount` or in `useEffect` if you are using hooks. The problem here likely is that by the time your component renders your request did not even finish. Your `products_array` will be empty when your script is initially loading and rendering your app the first time.

Comment: No it's not empty, I console logged both the arrays same data is there in both of them.

Comment: Where did you log it? Please also show the code of the component. Where is the `axios` call in?

Comment: Just before exporting and right after importing, same result.

Comment: Are you aware that requests are async? That means when your script initially runs `products_array` will be an empty array. Every code that uses it before the request finished will only see an empty array. If you intention is to render those products your need to use component state which you update when the request finishes. Exporting a mutating array is a strong anti-pattern and likely not what you want. Please also show the component code.

Comment: Not in any component, doing the axios call(first snipped of code) in a seperate file and then importing that file and using data from that array to give initial state in a reducer

Comment: Okay I see but this is not a good practice. You either need to wait for your request to finish **before** you even render your app or you render it with a blank state and display a spinner (or some other kind of loading indicator) until your request finishes and you can update the state with your fetched data. What exactly do you mean with ` for some reason can't do use the map function for this array`. Is it empty or do you see any error?

Comment: Again, please also provide the code of the component where you attempt to use `products_array`. It will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have my laptop handy with me right now, can't share the code immediately

Comment: No error is shown at all even while compilation, the array has data available even after importing it(console logged it) , but the 'map' function or a for loop for that matter just won't execute on the 'products_array'

Comment: What do you mean *it won't execute*? Likely it is just empty which will result in your `.map()` function just returning an empty array. Empty arrays will be ignored by react when rendering.

Comment: That makes sense. What do you suggest, how should I go about this. I will share the GitHub link ASAP, you can take a look then.

Comment: See [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-platform-cun9d?file=/src/App.js) which reproduces your problem and look at the console logs. You will see that the array is empty during the first render. I will answer with a proposed solution when you posted the relevant code.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, i will share the code from my end ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the git repository to the project (http://github.com/sahilkandhari/store-ui). the above axios call is in the data folder and the import is being done in thr ProductsContainer reducer which is in store->reducer->ProductsConatiner

Comment: From the codesandbox expamle if I relate to my case, the array is being logged in the console at line 17 of fetching.jd and even at line 6 in App.js

Comment: I only put the `console.log()`s there for you to see that the array is empty until the `.then()` of the `axios.get()` has been called. That means it will most likely be empty during the first render and during reducing the initial state of your redux store.

Comment: You can't load initial state for a react app like that. you have two options: You defer initialization of your react app until the request completed. But then your app will not show for the time the request needs to complete. Or (which is the better way) you load your app with an empty product list, show a loading indicator and dispatch an action to update your state as soon as the data is available. Also your product list must actually be in the redux store, not somewhere as a global.